# Java takes the variable as "final" even though it is not

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a code for my cs101 lesson and it includes making a BigNum class with arrays (So, there is no need to look for performance; and I've cropped the code a bit to make it more readable).

```
 public class BigNum{

    public static final int SIZE = 8;
    public static final int BASE = 10;   
    private int[] bigNumber;
    private int numberLength;

    public BigNum(String number){  //One of the constructors
       numberLength = number.length();
       bigNumber = new int[SIZE];
       for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
          if(SIZE-i > number.length()){
             bigNumber[i] = 0;
          }
          else{
             bigNumber[i] = Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(SIZE-1-i));
          }          
       }
    }

    public String toString(){  //toString function for the class
       String bigNum;
       bigNum = "";
       for(int i = 0; i < this.numberLength; i++){
          bigNum = bigNum + Integer.toString(bigNumber[SIZE-1-i]); 
       }
       return bigNum;
    }

    public int add(BigNum other){  //adds one number to another and
       int sum;                    //returns the overflowed digit
       String stringResult;
       sum = Integer.parseInt(this.toString()) + Integer.parseInt(other.toString());
       stringResult = Integer.toString(sum);
       this = new BigNum(stringResult);
       return (sum/((int)Math.pow(10,SIZE)));
     }  

  }
```

At the last method, i use "this" expression to redefine the object I've initialized before (In main method, I use it as [bigNumber1.add(bigNumber2);]). The error I am getting is:

```
1 error found:
File: H:\Java\cs101\lab10\BigNum.java  [line: 86]
Error: cannot assign a value to final variable this
```

I fear that I didn't understand the concept of "this", since I am pretty sure that I haven't defined any object as final and didn't touch any of the final variables in that section. Is there any way to get rid of this situation?

Any help will be useful. Thanks for advance!

Comment: What did you attempt to do with `this = ...`?

Comment: how should that work that you are changing the instance of an object itself while it is executing a method on it?

Comment: Which line is line 86?

Comment: `this` is the object you're calling the method on. You can't assign itself out from under itself. And you don't need to.

Comment: I am trying to add the sum of two numbers as a new defined object, to the reference I am initializing by method. Like: bigNumber1.add(bigNumber2);  [bigNumber1 should maintain the sum at the end of the method.]

Comment: Line 86: `this = new BigNum(stringResult);`. This cannot work, you don't use `this` this way.

Comment: if you want to add the sum of two numbers to a new defined object you use `BigNum sum = new BigNum(stringResult)`.

Comment: I understand that i can't use "this" this way, but what I am asking is: 1-why? 2-what should I do instead

Comment: Because that's a reference to the object you're in. You can't make it go away while you're in it. What to do instead has been pointed out already.

Comment: Hmm. So I can't change the object while i am using it, and that makes sense. Is there any way to do this, then? And why does it say that I am trying to change a final variable? (Line 86 is the line with this= ... btw.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can say this is a **final instance reference**  variable.

instance reference variable -> by default JVM assigns current object reference is this keyword.

final -> you can't assign any new value to this keyword 
So if you will do s.o.p (this);

Then J.V.M will print some hashcode of that object. which you can't change.

So it is illegal to use this = new BigNum(stringResult);

Comment: OOH That is it! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

`this = new BigNum(stringResult);` is invali syntax. `this` can only refer to the instance for which the `add` method was invoked.

If you wish to modify the state of that instance, and you wish to execute the same logic as in your constructor, you should extract that logic to a regular method.

```
public BigNum(String number){  //One of the constructors
    init (number);
}

private void init (String number) {
   numberLength = number.length();
   bigNumber = new int[SIZE];
   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
      if(SIZE-i > number.length()){
         bigNumber[i] = 0;
      }
      else{
         bigNumber[i] = Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(SIZE-1-i));
      }          
   }
}

public int add (BigNum other) {  //adds one number to another and
   int sum;                    //returns the overflowed digit
   String stringResult;
   sum = Integer.parseInt(this.toString()) + Integer.parseInt(other.toString());
   stringResult = Integer.toString(sum);
   init (stringResult);
   return (sum/((int)Math.pow(10,SIZE)));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign anything to `this`, it isn't a real variable, just a way to access instance members that have the same name as a local variable or obtain a reference to the current object. (Roughly speaking.)

What I suspect you were trying to do is update the current object with the result, in which case what you need to do is update all the real fields of your object (`bigNumber` and `numberLength`) with the new values separately.

My advice is to write a method like this:

```
private void updateFromString(String s) {
   bigNumber = ...;
   numberLength = ...;
}
```

And you can call that both from the `add()` method and your constructor. (It is important that the method is private, because it is invoked from the constructor, but that's a different topic.)

Comment: That one is a satisfying answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`this` is **not** a variable, it's a keyword.

I'm quoting the [**JLS - 15.8.3. this**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html):

> The **keyword** `this` may be used only in the body of an instance method, instance initializer, or constructor, or in the initializer of an instance variable of a class. If it appears anywhere else, a compile-time error occurs.

Also:

> When used as a primary expression, the **keyword** `this` denotes a *value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked* (§15.12), or to the object being constructed.

Answer (score 1):

`this` isn't a variable, and you cannot assign to it.

If you want to create a new `BigNum` as the result of the `add` operation (which is common in classes like this, see Java's own `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`), you'll need to do just that: Create a *new* one, and return it. (And then do something else to provide what you're currently returning.)

Alternately, if you want `add` to modify the state of your existing `BigNum` instance, assign to its fields `numberLength` and `bigNumber` (as you did in the constructor), not to `this` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use this is not correct:

```
   this = new BigNum(stringResult);
```

But you can do this:

```
   BigNum bigNum= new BigNum(stringResult);
```

Because In java, `this` is a reference variable that refers to the current object.